# How to send a HTTP OPTIONS request from the command line?

Tags: curl, wget

I tried to use cURL but it seems that by default (Debian) is not compiled with HTTPS support and I dont want to build it myself.

`wget` seems to have SSL support but I found no information on how to generate an OPTIONS HTTP request with wget.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't support HTTPS? Maybe it's just not willing to accept the remote site's certificate. The `-k` option tells it to ignore certificate errors, and that may help.

Answer (score 168):

The curl installed by default in Debian supports HTTPS since a great while back. (a long time ago there were two separate packages, one with and one without SSL but that's not the case anymore)

### OPTIONS /path

You can send an OPTIONS request with curl like this:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS http://example.org/path
```

You may also use `-v` instead of `-i` to see more output.

### OPTIONS *

To send a plain * (instead of the path, see [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7)) with the OPTIONS method, you need curl 7.55.0 or later as then you can run a command line like:

```
curl -i --request-target "*" -X OPTIONS http://example.org
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to use the "-v" flag too, if you want to see the response (check for the "Allow" header).

Comment: `-i` also works to let you see output and is a bit less noisy than `-v`

Comment: Any idea how to get it to send `OPTIONS *`, as described in [rfc2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)?

Comment: @theory: it is coming soon: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2017/06/19/options-with-curl/