# Is it possible to send "OPTIONS *" with cURL?

Tags: http, curl

From [RFC7230 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#asterisk-form)

> When a client wishes to request OPTIONS for the server as a whole, as opposed to a specific named resource of that server, the client must send only "*" (%x2A) as the request-target.

To test how my site reacts I want to send the following request to the server.

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
```

I know I can use telnet, write my own client, etc.
But I want to know if it's possible to do it with cURL?

**Edit**
This can NOT be done with `curl -X OPTIONS http://example.org`, as suggested in [a similar, but not identical, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481850/how-to-send-a-http-options-request-from-the-command-line) That command will send `OPTIONS http://example.org/ HTTP/1.1`. I want to know if it's possible to send the asterisk with cURL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a HTTP OPTIONS request from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481850/how-to-send-a-http-options-request-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That command will send "OPTIONS /" not "OPTIONS *".

Comment: RFC 2616 is obsolete. You may want to cite https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#asterisk-form instead. (no, it doesn't change the nature of the question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `-X OPTIONS` only will send a slash and not an asterisk as path in the request.

In order to send a plain `OPTIONS *` to the server with curl, you need curl 7.55.0 or later and its [--request-target](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--request-target) option in addition to the `-X` flag. Used like this:

```
curl -X OPTIONS --request-target '*' https://example.com/
```

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to do this for months. I even resorted to reading the curl code but abandoned that in preference for looking at Chrome extensions. I would be happy to fix it if you could point me to the right place. (nickshanks on github)

Comment: To me its not about where to "fix it", but rather "how" . No other HTTP method can do plain `*` like that so we need to figure out something new. I would recommend taking your ideas and discussions for that to the curl-library mailing list.

Comment: Regarding https://cool.haxx.se/mailman/listinfo/curl-library the subscribe form action is http not https

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I think I've fixed the mailman subscription now to use HTTPS there as well!

Answer (score -1):

You can send custom requests with cURL by using the -x option, https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x

So this command would look like this

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://example.com
```

Comment: Not the same thing. That command will send a OPTIONS / request, not with asterix.