# send requests with different HTTP methods

Tags: http, browser, server, http-method

How can I send different HTTP request **methods** over my browser? I am using chrome, but any other would do.

For example, I would like to try out `TRACE` or `OPTIONS` methods for educational purposes. Any idea how I can do that?

Example:

request message:

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
Host: www.joes-hardware.com 
Accept: *
```

response message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS 
Context-length: 0
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would want to do that through your browser?

Comment: There is no exact need for browser. I just though browsers have this option enabled. Any other tool would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers themselves do not issue any requests with verbs (read: methods) other than `GET`, `POST`, and `HEAD`. By the powers of [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) though, they can be made to use a wealth of other methods through the [XmlHttpRequest](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/) object. However, you will be [out of luck](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#request-method) with the `TRACE` verb:

> If *method* is a case-sensitive match for `CONNECT`, `TRACE`, or `TRACK`, throw a "[SecurityError](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#securityerror)" exception and terminate these steps.

If you do not want or do not need to be bound to a browser, there are quite a few options. For starters, Perl's [libwww](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) library comes with the `GET`, `HEAD`, and `POST` commandline utilities that are quite neat to use.

A more complete solution is [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/), which is a pretty complete solution for a multitude of protocols. Its original purpose has been to simply catch a file from an URL (**c**atch **URL** = **cURL**) which does not necessarily mean from an HTTP server. With a well-formed URL, cURL can download an attachment from an e-mail on an IMAP server. You will be most interested into the `-X` option of cURL's commandline interface, which allows you to specify arbitrary verbs for an HTTP request. But as mighty as it may be, there will probably be [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36933053/3012385) to issue that `OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1` request with it.

As a last-ditch effort, I can wholeheartedly recommend [netcat](https://nmap.org/ncat/), which accepts piped input and is fully able to handle encryption (which is way more comfortable than openssl's s_client). You may already know that you can emulate HTTP requests over telnet (if you type fast enough). But I believe you will find netcat with some [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) way more comfortable:

```
$ nc -v localhost 80 <<EOD
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: close

EOD
```

netcat speaks no HTTP itself, so you alone are responsible for the syntactical correctness of your requests. On the other hand, this allows you total freedom to experiment around.