# How to send ‘OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1’ requests with the fetch() JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, http-options-method

From [RFC 9110, HTTP Semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-9.3.7-2):

> An OPTIONS request with an asterisk ("*") as the request target (Section 7.1) applies to the server in general rather than to a specific resource. Since a server's communication options typically depend on the resource, the "*" request is only useful as a "ping" or "no-op" type of method; it does nothing beyond allowing the client to test the capabilities of the server. For example, this can be used to test a proxy for HTTP/1.1 conformance (or lack thereof).

I wrote an HTTP server in JavaScript running on Node and would like to write a unit test for checking how it responds to the following request:

```http
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
```

**How to send that request using the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) JavaScript API?**

I know that it is possible with Curl using the [`--request-target`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--request-target) option (the question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36925133/2326961) on Stack Overflow):

```bash
curl --request-target '*' -X OPTIONS https://example.com/
```

Comment: You can set the method to `OPTIONS`. See [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) for more info.

Comment: @Reyno I know but how do you specify the asterisk request target?

Comment: I doubt this is possible with fetch unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It is not possible to issue HTTP request with `OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1` [start line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#start_line) in JavaScript

I have scourged all documentations of both `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` and found no way to change the "request target resource" part of the HTTP request *start line* ("prologue").

All JS APIs derive content of the *start line* from the method and URL, while the resource is always the "path" part of the URL and defaults to "`/`".

There is no way to tell JS to issue request with "`*`" in place where the default `/` normally occurs.

On top of that, there does not seem to be any other low-level alternative that would let us construct whole HTTP request payload including *start line* "by hand", so there are likely no workarounds possible.

---

Posting as clear answer for current states of things and documentations.  Would be happy to be proven wrong.