# Enabling CORS on StrongLoop backed ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, strongloop

I have a loopback API server configured with Passport running on port 3000. My UI is composed by react JS which is being served from port 3080. I want to implement authentication with Google. For this, from my react application, I am making a call to 
`localhost:3000/auth/google`
But the call is not getting redirected to google because of the CORS error :

`Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/auth/google. Redirect from 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google' to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=h…d=584602753475-1kk345gd8trcn31pbg1v2gncajhpakk8.apps.googleusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.`

When I hit `http://localhost:3000/auth/google` url from a fresh browser tab, everything is working fine.

Can anyone tell where should I enable the cors ?

**Edit**

I could see that, the browser is making an options request to localhost:3000/auth/google

This is what I got when I made an options request with curl : 

`HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 14:05:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to enable CORS in Strongloop or ReactJS, but to enable it you need two things:

```
1. The right configuration of the JS request like so:

var params = {
  …
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include' //<- that gave me some headache a while ago,
                         //but is probably not necessary in your case. 
  …
}

fetch(new Request(<url>, params).then(res => …);
```

2. The right server configuration. A cors request will first call the server with a preflight request, which should tell the browser if it may access this resource, including all headers. This request uses the http OPTIONS method/verb so your server needs to respond on that correctly. If it does, the Browser will perform the actual request you want to do.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have this part in my JS fetch request. And the browser makes an Options request to `http://localhost:3000/auth/google` . This is where things get blocked.

Comment: did you test the options request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481850/how-to-send-a-http-options-request-from-the-command-line

Comment: I tried an Options request. Response is : `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 14:05:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: I guess there is a header for the allowed `content-type` missing. Are trying to post/receive json?

Comment: that enpoint returns an html page with content type text/html;

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think I should add origin in my loopback server(3000). But I am not sure how to.